# blogdown can't find updated version of Hugo

Tags: r, blogdown

While attempting to build a theme with `blogdown` and Hugo, I encountered the following error: `ERROR 2017/12/01 19:34:06 Current theme does not support Hugo version 0.19. Minimum version required is 0.2`.

However, I do have an updated version (0.31.1) of Hugo:

```
system("hugo version")

Hugo Static Site Generator v0.31.1 darwin/amd64 BuildDate: 2017-12-01T19:36:01-08:00
```

And `blogdown` cannot find it:

```
> blogdown::hugo_version()
[1] ‘0.19’
```

Is this a path issue I need to fix on my machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you `blogdown::update_hugo()`, you may need to restart your R session. If that does not fix your problem, run `blogdown:::find_hugo()`; if it returns a path under `~/Library/Application Support`, delete the `Hugo` directory under it, e.g., `unlink('~/Library/Application Support/Hugo', recursive = TRUE)`. Then `blogdown::install_hugo()`.

Comment: Thanks Yihui! Loving it!

Answer (score 0):

Met the same problem and Yihui's solution works.
To summarise:

`unlink('~/Library/Application Support/Hugo', recursive = TRUE)
blogdown::install_hugo(force=TRUE)`

Then restart R.